# Find current value with class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this script:

```
var a = $(this).find('.q').val();
```

I'm trying to find the value for every `.q` input, but I seem to have got someting wrong. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong?

Update: I have multiple `.q` elements.

Comment: where is the rest of your code?

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have multiple `.q` elements you need to loop over them:

```
$(this).find('.q').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    // do something with the value here...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to receive a list/array, like this:

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

where "foo" and "bar" are each values of `.q` elements.

If I'm right, here's what you want:

```
var listOfValues = $(this).find('.q').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
});
```

`listOfValues` will contain an array-like list of all values of each `.q` element. This is all thanks to the `map` function. More information here: http://api.jquery.com/map/

> Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

Comment: Or just `var listOfValues = $('.q').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
});`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss He specifically included `$(this)` in his question so it's possible this code is going to be in a place where the context is important; like a event listener callback, for example. Other than that all you did is remove some CRLF from my code making it arguably harder to read so... Cool? I guess?